# Iphone: media css code does not work

Tags: css

I have this @media setup

```
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
CSS:

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    /* STYLES HERE */
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 768px) { 
    /* STYLES HERE */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* STYLES HERE */
}
```

With this setup in works to view it on the iPhone but it does not work in the browser. It's really irritating so help is highly appreciated. Is it because I already have device in the meta and maybe have (max-width:480px) instead?

Comment: I think there's no `max-device-width` for desktop browser when considering the browser width. It's `max-width` like you guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear if you could clarify, what do yo mean it does not work in the browser?  What does not work in the browser?

---

This is what your queries mean to me:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {}
```

This says for a modern mobile device (older mobile devices don't fall under the screen category but newer iPhones do) or desktop device with a screen that is 769 pixels wide or larger apply this. (Desktop)  You could abbreviate this as @media (min-width:769px) and achieve the same result.

Note that iPhones that fall under the 'screen' category will base this on their current orientation.  So portrait and landscape must be treated separately.

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 768px) { }
```

For a device with a minimum screen resolution of 481 pixels wide but no more than 768 pixels wide, do this..

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
```

For modern devices with a maximum screen resolution of 480px do this..

None of your media queries relate to iPhones because your using max-device-width which is equivalent to the devices resolution and an iPhones resolution is far greater than 480 or even 768.  I think its something around 1280 (I'd have to look it up).  But the easier fix would be to use max-width or you could combine them:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:768px), (max-width:768px) {}
```

---

Further reading:

[CSS3 Media Query Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)